# Moving, Removing, Disabling Administration on live server

Tags: 7, users

On my staging server people should be able to access the administration to add, delete or edit content. The complete installation including the database is then deployed to a live server. On the live server I don't want anyone to be able to access the administration. In other words if a user goes to `mylivesite.com/admin` the response would be a `404 - not found`. What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to deny access to the administration pages for certain roles on your live site using standard Drupal permissions ( http://example.com/admin/people/permissions ).

The permission you're looking for is called "Use the administration pages and help".

Returning a 404 for all admin pages doesn't seem like the correct thing to do here, as the page *has* been found. A 403 is the correct semantic response for this.

If you're desperate, having the following code in a module on your live site only would do the trick:

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  if (arg(0) == 'admin' && $GLOBALS['user']->uid != 1) {
    drupal_not_found();
  }
}
```

But I can't say I'd recommend it :)

Comment: Dammit...I was typing pretty much exactly the same answer :-(

Comment: I think one of my clients is using a variation on the hook_init() thing with good results.